# implement compareTo in generic class

Tags: java, generics, comparable, compareto

I wrote a class with this prototype:

```
public class AkbarWorks<T implements Comparable>
```

This class contains 2 ArrayLists:

```
private ArrayList<T> elements = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<T> removed = new ArrayList<>();
```

My problem is, I want to compare 2 Objects of T, but compareTo does not work, and I could not override it. I use compareTo in this function:

```
 public T getMin() throws IllegalStateException {
    if (elements.size() == 0) {
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    } else {
        T min = elements.get(0);
        for (int i = 1; i < elements.size(); i++) {
            if (elements.get(i).compareTo(min) < 0)
                min = elements.get(i);
        }
        return min;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the answer is : T must extends Comparable not implements.